# How exactly is Multibit HD more secure than Multibit Classic?

Tags: multibit, multibit-hd

In what ways is Multibit HD more secure than the old, no longer supported, Classic version? What are the differences in threat models, wallet recovery, and other areas a Bitcoin user would care about?

I haven't found anything about this on multibit.org.